# get the sub pages of the parent page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the following code to display the subpages pages of a parent page with id 67 , although it should return 3 pages but it is returning only two pages .

```
<?php
      $mypages = get_pages( array( 
       'child_of' => 67, 
        'sort_column' => 'post_modified',
        'sort_order' => 'desc', 
        'number'=>3
                     ) );
       echo count($mypages);                         
 ?>
```

But when i don't use the argument 'number'=3, then everything is fine and it returns 3 pages. What is it that i am doing wrong.
Please help me

Comment: which version of WP you are running ?

Comment: Above code is working fine in Version 3.9

Comment: i am too using version 3.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one and check what your are getting.

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'sort_order' => 'ASC',
        'sort_column' => 'post_title',
        'hierarchical' => 1,
        'exclude' => '',
        'include' => '',
        'meta_key' => '',
        'meta_value' => '',
        'authors' => '',
        'child_of' => 0,
        'parent' => 67,
        'exclude_tree' => '',
        'number' => '',
        'offset' => 0,
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    );
    $pages = get_pages($args);

    print_r($pages);
?>
```